Python - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' - non-escabable characters?
So I am trying to do an iterative search through a file using a list of all the patterns I want it to search for. It returns a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
I'm searching csv with IPv6 addresses in it, so what I suspect is happening is it is seeing the ":" in my search patterns and then thinks its a dictionary?
So I think I have to escape the :, but my google searches seem to come up that the : is no longer escapable (as of 3.7)? Or my google-fu is just failing me this sunday evening.
Python 3.8
import re
from datetime import datetime


def count_matching_lines(filename, dvc_ptrns):
    count = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for pattern in dvc_ptrns:
                if re.search(pattern, line):
                    count += 1
                    print(count)
    return count


## Define paths
devpath = f'/home/user'
rootpath = devpath

# Get current date for logging
current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')

# File paths
filtered_file = f'{rootpath}/filtered{current_date}.csv'


filename = filtered_file  # Replace with your file


ptrn_print = '2022:28'
ptrn_wlsap = ['2022:34e','2022:34f']
dvc_ptrns = [ptrn_print, ptrn_wlsap]

count = count_matching_lines(filename, dvc_ptrns)


print("Number of matching lines:", count)

Edit: forgot to add the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipv6_dev_count.py", line 36, in <module>
    count = count_matching_lines(filename, dvc_ptrns)
  File "ipv6_dev_count.py", line 12, in count_matching_lines
    if re.search(pattern, line):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 201, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 294, in _compile
    return _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'


If you print(dvc_ptrns) immediately after the assignment to dvc_ptrns, you will see your error

This error occurs because dvc_ptrns contains a nested list ptrn_wlsap.
When you iterate over dvc_ptrns in your count_matching_lines function, Python treats ptrn_wlsap as a list, which isn't hashable and cannot be used directly in a re.search function. In other words, in the second iteration of if re.search(pattern, line):, pattern results to ['2022:34e','2022:34f'] which the re.search function doesn't expect. It expects a string.
To fix this, you have to flatten dvc_ptrns to a single list of strings like so:
dvc_ptrns = [ptrn_print] + ptrn_wlsap


The error occurs because you are trying to include a list (ptrn_wlsap) within another list (dvc_ptrns). When you iterate over dvc_ptrns, the re.search function expects each pattern to be a string, but instead, it encounters a list.
dvc_ptrns = [ptrn_print] + ptrn_wlsap


Changed to:
dvc_ptrns = ptrn_print + [ptrn_wlsap]
and that now returns error
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str


ptrn_print should be the one in square brackets not ptrn_wlsap.

you should concatenate [ptrn_print] with the list ptrn_wlsap.
